# Is there a way to hack blender to import .HEIF images HEVC and h.265 codec videos?

Tags: import, image, video, versions

Is there a way to modify the source code, or other hacks, to import images in [HEIF format](https://nokiatech.github.io/heif/examples.html) or h.265 video (like pictures and movies made with iphones and other samsung phones) into Blender directly? I'm trying to avoid transcoding.

[image]

[OpenImageIO v 2.2](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio) supports such formats, and blender uses OIIO to open images, right?
There's got to be some kind of hack to import them, I would hope.
Natron uses the same library and the images open just fine.

Comment: FFmpeg version (4.3) seems to support it, there is no UI option though.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: So far no answers.